# Performance with EAGLView on top of other views

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, blending

I have to overlay an (mostly) transparent OpenGL view on top of some other views in my iOS app, but testing on my iPod touch (first gen, albeit, iPhone OS 3.1) gives really bad performance. I have read the http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH1-SW1(OpenGL ES Programming Guide) over att Apple which discourages overlaying OpenGL views on top of others. But I need the threaded drawing power which OpenGL views have.

So my question is just pointers on minimising the impact of blending the EAGLView on top of other views. Testing has shown that the blending alone accounts for 30% of the running time. Any ideas?

What I'm looking for is perhaps just configurations for the OpenGL view, like buffer size or byte size or what it could be.

The app is: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kick-ass-destroy-the-web/id436623109?mt=8

Comment: As you have correctly spotted, Apple simply discourages such constructs. Any reason you are not using a grabbed version of the web-views etc. as a texture below your "game"?

Comment: How do you mean grabbed? Grab an image and add it as texture and background? I need the webview to work like a normal webview.

Answer (score 1):

This slide would help you to improve OpenGL rendering performance with UIKit.

- The Best of Both Worlds: Using UIKit with OpenGL

  - [Slide](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1012504/The-Best-of-Both-Worlds)
  - [Audio](https://store.cmpgame.com/product/5914/The-Best-of-Both-Worlds%3a-Using-UIKit-with-OpenGL)